# If G is finite group with even number of elements and has identity e, there is a in G such that a*a=e

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

My approach is ;

I subtract e from G then G-{e} has odd number of elements.

For any element in G-{e}, there must be an inverse of that element in G-{e}.

Take any element in G-{e}, say b,  If b*b=e, then proof is done.

If inverse of b is not itself, then there must be one element in G-{e}, say c, such that b*c=e.

Because there are odd number of elements, I keep doing this until I have left with one

element that does not have a pair, say d.

any other elements in G-{e} can not be inverse of d because they all have pairs, and e can not be an inverse of d.

Therefore d has to be inverse of itself.

Is my proof valid? or Can anyone modify it please?

Comment: $G - \{ e \}$ isn't a group, there would be no inverse.

Comment: I assume that you mean "there is $a\in G$, $a\ne e$ such that $a^2=e$." Otherwise trivially $e^2=e$.

Comment: You might look at [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) for a generalization of the result you're trying to prove.

Comment: Looks like a proof to me. Maybe people are getting confused by the the second line ("For any element in $G - \lbrace e \rbrace$ there must be an inverse of that element in $G - \lbrace e \rbrace$"); I think your proof reads better if you just delete that line.

Comment: You are basically correct. Pair an element and its inverse. $e$ is its own inverse, and so there must be some other element $a$ with $a^{-1}=a$, as the group has even order. Your argument seems a little too long for me.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that for all $a\in G$ with $a\ne e$ that $a^2\ne e$. Then $a\ne a^{-1}$. Hence there are an even number of non-identity elements in $G$. But this contradicts the assumption that $G$ has an even number of elements.

Comment: The OP wanted a confirmation of whether the proof presented was valid or not. Your answer doesn't deal with this main question- you provided a proof similar to that of the OP, without telling her whether her proof was on the right track or not.

Comment: You say "Hence there are an even number of nonidentity elements in G." I don't understand how this follows from the fact that $a \neq a^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct.

Or, leaving out the disjoint union of subsets with $2$ elements $\{ b, b^{-1}\}$ where $b \ne b^{-1}$, an even number of elements are left. $e$ being one of those left, there has to be some more $b$'s not $e$ with $b^2 = e$ ( an odd number of them).